# Como evitar o erro "zend_mm_heap corrupted"?

Tags: php

No meu dia a dia de desenvolvimento PHP e entrega de releases, volta e meia recebo o seguinte erro quando um build é feito em nosso ambiente de integração contínua:

```
zend_mm_heap corrupted
```

Trata-se de um erro fatal, que trava o script de deploy e tenho que mandar construir o build novamente.

Do que se trata esse erro, e como posso evitá-lo?

Obrigado!

Comment: Na verdade no título o erro está correto, mas no corpo estava errado (escrevi "zend_mm_head"). Agora deve ficar um pouco mais fácil de tentar descobrir a causa :)

Answer (score 1):

Não entendo muito sobre o assunto, mas dando uma pesquisada pelo [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean), resolvi trazer uma tradução, para ver se posso ajudar alguém.

## Possíveis soluções:

**Aumentar o output buffering**

De acordo com a resposta do próprio autor da pergunta no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453898/3096922), ele configurou o `php.ini`, aumentando o tamanho do `output_buffering`. Ao ser questionado sobre "o que o output buffer tem a ver com isso", ele justificou-se usando essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832179/3096922);

**Configurar USE_ZEND_ALLOC**:

De acordo com uma das respostas da questão em inglês acima, o problema foi resolvido utilizando o comando no `bash`:

```
export USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0
```

Uma sugestão de definir essa variável no arquivo `/etc/apache2/envvars` foi dada em um comentário da resposta no SOEN

**Desabilitar o opcache**:

Segundo uma das respostas, ao desabilitar o `opcache`, o problema foi resolvido:

```
 opcache.enable_cli=0
```